# Block all users except localhost from phpmyadmin and mysql

Tags: mysql, apache, security, phpmyadmin, xampp

I recently installed the XAMPP stack on a desktop and connected via a laptop on the local network.  To my surprise, I was able to access phpmyadmin and delete update all mysql tables.  Though I understand that I shouldn't use xampp for production (and I'm not), I would still like to learn how to manage these types of obvious security flaws. I know that I can block access to directories via .htacces (http://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=29089), but I would like something that is a little more comprehensive.  How would you restrict running of mysql queries from anywhere except localhost?  Is there a way without .htaccess? I thought this was partially the purpose of the root user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL defined users with domains. If you look at your `user_privileges` table in the `information_schema` database you will see that they all have domains. If all your users are defined strictly as localhost, there will be no remote access.

Also, you can edit my.cnf to turn off tcp access to the database, forcing all connections to be by socket. under `[mysqld]`, include the line `skip-networking`. You will have to configure all your apps to use the socket connection, but I like the socket better anyway.

This will do nothing to protect your data from someone using phpMyAdmin, if phpMyAdmin is installed on the same machine as the database. The *safest* thing to do is get rid of that app. That's often not practical, however, as it's a useful tool, and so you need to configure phpMyAdmin to require that users authenticate themselves. That means NOT putting the password in the config file. You will need to think about how long sessions are before reauthentication, and things like that.

phpMyAdmin fills me with a rage hotter than a thousand suns whenever I try to configure it, but it is definitely possible to set things up so a password is required each time you connect to the database through phpMyAdmin. You can further limit the damage phpMyAdmin abusers can do my making sure it only connects as a user with limited privileges (for instance, only able to modify the database you're working on at the moment).